# Равномерное распределение пользователей по группам

Tags: php

У меня есть n кол-во пользователей, которых нужно распределить по n кол-ву групп.
Например:

```
$users = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$groups = [1 => 0, 2 => 1, 3 => 2]; //ключ = номер группы, значение = кол-во пользователей в группе на текущий момент
```

Например, на выходе должно получиться так, что в первую группу уйдет 4 юзера, во вторую 3, в третью 2

```
[1 => 4, 2 => 4, 3 => 4]
```

+1 еще должен рандомно попасть в одну из групп так как на выходе получится, что у каждой по 4 пользователя.

Вопрос в том, как мне учесть кол-во текущих пользователей в группах?
Просто через `array_chunk` не прокатит...

Comment: Готовой такой функции нет. Вам придется последовательно "бежать" по массиву групп и "откусывать" от массива пользователей нехватку онных в текущей группе.

Comment: Берём группу с минимальным количеством пользователей. Добавляем в неё первого пользователя. Повторяем.

Comment: @AlexeyTen думал так сделать, но дело в том что массив из этих юзеров может быть 1к++ id и не хочется циклом проходить по всему массиву...

Comment: не хочется, а придется.

Comment: Может такой вариант: считаем среднее количество которое должно получится в группах (10 пользователей + 0 + 1 + 2 = 13 / 3 группы = 4.333 округляем до меньшего целого - 4) теперь в каждую группу добавляем до среднего т.е в первую 4 пользователя ( 4 - 0), во вторую 3 (4 - 1), в третью 2 (4-2), последнего рандомно, последних можно считать как общее количество - среднее * кол-во групп (13 - 4 * 3 = 1) - вот одного рандомно добавляем в какую-либо группу